# Laravel append image path to array of object

Tags: laravel

for make an api to return all images of the doctor

```
$images = Doctor::select('image')->get();
```

so the response is like the

```
`[
  { image: 111.png },
  { image: 222.png },
  { image: 333.png }
 ]`
```

then i return the images

```
return $images
```

I want to append the path to the image before return it like

> mypath/222.png

i can do this with a for loop put i thank that made a more unnecessary complexity

so is their a way to make it in the eloquent

Comment: Look for eloquent map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's how you want to get the image column every time then accessor is the best option. In your `Doctor` model:

```
public function getImageAttribute($value){
    return 'mypath/'.$value;
}
```

If you want it only in this place then you can use `map`:

```
$images = Doctor::select('image')->get()->map(function($doctor){
    $doctor->image = 'mypath/'.$doctor->image;
    return $doctor;
});
```

and you will have your desired result.